# Bootstrap CSS CDN loading in some system and not in others

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I recently noticed that `bootstrap.min.css` is not getting loaded for one of my website on some browsers while its getting loaded in other browsers. The URL for CDN is https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css. I also tried opening them in **Incognito/Private** mode too to avoid loading from cache, but this file is still not able to load on some browsers' private mode, while it's loading in some browser's private mode. The restriction is that I don't have access to modify the HTML code. Also, I don't think anything is wrong syntactically as it's working fine in private mode of some browsers.

I have tried to open on couple of windows desktop systems. The result are as follows for their **Incognito/Private** mode:

```
----------------------------------------
|         | Chrome | Firefox | MS Edge |
|---------|--------|---------|---------|
|System 1 |   No   |   No    |    No   |
|System 2 |   No   |   Yes   |    -    |
|System 3 |   No   |   No    |    No   |
|System 4 |   Yes  |   Yes   |    Yes  | 
----------------------------------------
Yes - loading fine
No - not loading fine
```

To verify if it is getting loaded or not, I checked *Networks* tab under *Inspect Element*.

**Question:**
Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: Really difficult to give you a solution since you don't have access to the code, but I would check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415254/bootstrap-css-not-working-in-chrome-or-firefox) and see if these solutions work.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared the cache and cookies from each browser and it's working fine for me in incognito/private mode of all the browsers. However, the thing that I still don't understand is why accessing in private/incognito mode was affected by cache and/or cookies of the browser?