# How to create jumbotron in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

In Bootstrap 5 the jumbotron component is removed in favor of utility classes like .bg-light for the background color and .p-* classes to control padding.  I'm a newbie, can somebody give example of how to do that?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The migration documents give you exactly what you need to know.  In v4.x Bootstrap's `.jumbotron` component is literally just this:

```
.jumbotron {
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  border-radius: .3rem;
}
```

You can, with the exception of the specific background color, emulate this entirely without the use of this class:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h5>In Bootstrap v4.x</h5>

<div class="jumbotron m-3">
  <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h5>In Bootstrap v5.x</h5>

<div class="bg-light p-5 rounded-lg m-3">
  <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
</div>
```

That being said, if you are a novice Bootstrap I would strongly recommend holding off trying to master v5.x which is currently in alpha and subject to any number of changes.

Comment: I got a fixed navbar which is taken out of flow, so I tried to push the Bootstrap 5 jumbotron with py-5. It works but the jumbotron still overlaps with the navbar a little bit.  What is the best way to push the Bootstrap 5 jumboron down?

Comment: yeah mt-5 same effect.

Comment: could you recreate your issue on online ide like jsfiddle or stackblitz ?

Comment: ah! makes sense now. The best solution to your problem is to add top padding to the body. so try adding `pt-3` to `body` and experiment with the number to get your desired result.

Comment: pt-3 is that the default height of fixed navbar?

Comment: @Djangonow `.pt-3` is a Bootstrap utility class that applies padding to the top margin. It ranges from 0 - 5. Like I said in my original response, reviewing the Bootstrap Docs will be an invaluable resource for you - especially when v5 moves to public release. The utility classes can achieve a lot of what are currently components within Bootstrap 4.x.

Comment: It's a great substitute of the Jumbotron and works perfectly. Wonder, why Bootstrap removed it in V5. Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 8):

I just use some of the basic container and padding bootstrap 5 class here's an example:

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-dark text-light p-5">
    <div class="container bg-dark p-5">
        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome to my Website</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>Go to My Website</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I mean it will look like a jumbotron

Answer (score 6):

As there is no Jumbotron in v5, If you are migrating to v5, the best way to reimplement it is to reuse the v4 jumbotron code.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-oesi62hOLfzrys4LxRF63OJCXdXDipiYWBnvTl9Y9/TRlw5xlKIEHpNyvvDShgf/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .jumbotron {
      padding: 4rem 2rem;
      margin-bottom: 2rem;
      background-color: var(--bs-light);
      border-radius: .3rem;  
    }
</style>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/ya37wk4c/2/

Answer (score 2):

The jumbotron component is removed in favor of utility classes like .bg-light for the background color and .p-* classes to control padding. Ref:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#jumbotron

you can try something like this

```
<div class="container-fluid text-sm-center p-5 bg-light"> <!-- bg-light is background color & p-5 is padding -->
    <h1 class="display-2">Full Stack Conf</h1>
    <p class="lead">A One-day Conference About All Things JavaScript!</p>
</div>
```

Find more examples here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/jumbotron/

Answer (score 2):

A **pure Bootstrap 5 solution** No CSS needed

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Document</title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>




    <header >
        <div class="container-fluid text-sm-center p-5 bg-light"> <!-- bg-light is background color & p-5 is padding -->
            <h1 class="display-2">Hasan Al-Sayyed</h1>
            <p class="lead">This is my first Github comment!</p>
        </div>
    </header>





<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: "jumboton" is not supported in Bootstrap 5
I think this approach is better
you can change the color with bg-dark ... etc

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a class, because it can be reproduced with utilities.

Here is an example of a jumbotron (Bootstrap v4) for Boostrap v5 :

```
    <div class="p-5 mb-4 bg-light rounded-3">
        <div class="container-fluid py-5">
            <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold">Custom jumbotron</h1>
            <p class="col-md-8 fs-4">Using a series of utilities, you can create this jumbotron, just like the one in
                previous versions of Bootstrap. Check out the examples below for how you can remix and restyle it to
                your liking.</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button">Example button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Source : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/jumbotron/

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code snippet:

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-light text-dark p-5">
  <div class="container bg-light p-5">
    <h1 class="display-4 fw-bold">Welcome to Admin Dashboard</h1>
    <hr>
      <p>Go to My Website</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also go to this link and use "inspect element" feature to make modifications in above code snippet as per you need. [Jumbotron Example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/jumbotron/)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Document</title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>




    <header >
        <div class="container-fluid text-sm-center p-5 bg-light"> <!-- bg-light is background color & p-5 is padding -->
            <h1 class="display-2">Hasan Al-Sayyed</h1>
            <p class="lead">This is my first Github comment!</p>
        </div>
    </header>





<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Exactly the same Jumbotron as Bootstrap 4
Just copy and paste it in the Code.

```
  <div class="container py-5 px-3 my-4 rounded" style="background:#E9ECEF">
        <h1 class="display-4 pb-2">Welcome to Python Forums</h1>
        <p class="lead">Python is a high-level, general-purpose programming language. Its design philosophy emphasizes code readability with the use of significant indentation. Its language constructs and object-oriented approach aim to help programmers write clear, logical code</p>
        <hr>
        <p class="py-2">This is peer to peer forum for sharing knowledge with each other</p>
        <div class="btn btn-primary">Learn more</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Jumbotron component for **Bootstrap v5**, based on the styles from v4.
The implementation uses CSS variables and it also supports dark mode.

```scss
$jumbotron-padding: 2rem;
$jumbotron-margin-bottom: $jumbotron-padding;
$jumbotron-color: inherit;
$jumbotron-bg: var(--#{$prefix}secondary-bg);
$jumbotron-border-radius: var(--#{$prefix}border-radius);

.jumbotron {
  --#{$prefix}jumbotron-padding: #{$jumbotron-padding};
  --#{$prefix}jumbotron-margin-bottom: #{$jumbotron-margin-bottom};
  --#{$prefix}jumbotron-color: #{$jumbotron-color};
  --#{$prefix}jumbotron-bg: #{$jumbotron-bg};
  --#{$prefix}jumbotron-border-radius: #{$jumbotron-border-radius};

  padding: var(--#{$prefix}jumbotron-padding)
    calc(var(--#{$prefix}jumbotron-padding) * 0.5);
  margin-bottom: var(--#{$prefix}jumbotron-margin-bottom);
  color: var(--#{$prefix}jumbotron-color);
  background: var(--#{$prefix}jumbotron-bg);
  border-radius: var(--#{$prefix}jumbotron-border-radius);

  @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
    padding: calc(var(--#{$prefix}jumbotron-padding) * 2)
      var(--#{$prefix}jumbotron-padding);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
  <p class="lead">
    This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.
  </p>
  <hr class="my-4" />
  <p>
    It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.
  </p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
</div>
```

**Example**:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-lpygag?file=src%2Fstyles.scss